# Wpf Open multi Window Mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

first sorry for my English

i have class person that has some properties

```
class Person
{
    //Properties
}
```

and Window Person Search this is View Model of this window contain list of person  and use Mvvm

```
class PersonSearchViewModel
{
    public PersonSearchViewModel(Person person)
    {
        SelectedPerson = person;
    }
    public Person SelectedPerson { set; get; }
    public ObservableCollection <Person> PersonList { set; get; }
}
```

and Window Person Information to insert and update

```
class PersonInformationView : Window
{
    public PersonInformationView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContex = vm;
    }

    PersonInforamtionViewModel vm = new PersonInforamtionViewModel();
    private void buttonOpenSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PersonSearchView p = new PersonSearchView(vm.PersonInfo);
    }
}
```

and the View Model Of this Window

```
class PersonInforamtionViewModel
{
    public Person PersonInfo { set; get; }
}
```

i need when open Window search from Window Person Information and selected person item  ...
Change Auto the property ===> PersonInfo 
**To achieve the class is one responsibility**

Comment: Is `PersonSearchView` the window that you are trying to open? What exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your are driving everything from the view. In MVVM it should be the VMs that are charge and driving everything. The views are just wrappers around the VMs

Currently you are creating `PersonSearchView` from `PersonInformationView`, but this gives you no visibility on the `PersonSearchViewModel` inside `PersonSearchView`, and it's `PersonSearchViewModel` that has `SelectedPerson`.

Instead you should be creating `PersonSearchViewModel` from `PersonInformationViewModel`. That way you can react to changes in `PersonSearchViewModel.SelectedPerson`, either by subscribing to `PropertyChanged`, or probably better by passing in a callback delegate into the `PersonSearchViewModel` constructor that it should call when a person selects a person.